# Cores em imagens

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

Eu possuo uma imagem e gostaria de pegar a cor predominante desta imagem.

Por exemplo:

Tenho esta imagem: http://etc.piktureplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Natural-Green-Wallpaper-for-Desktop-26.jpg

A cor predominante é o verde, gostaria de saber como identificar esta cor, em diferentes imagens, independente da cor que seja predominante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa biblioteca pode ajudar: https://github.com/fleitz/ColorArt

Com ela você pode extrair informações da imagem, como a cor de fundo.

Exemplo de uso:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
SLColorArt *colorArt = [image colorArt];
primaryColorView.backgroundColor = colorArt.primaryColor;
backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = colorArt.backgroundColor;
```